# Python removing newline characters from beginning and ending of each item in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm new at Python, and I'm trying to pull a list of artists and songs from Billboard's Hot 100 charts.  I'm getting newline characters in my list of artists.  How can I remove them without messing up the pairing and appearance of the list?

What I have:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
songs = tree.xpath('//h2[@class="chart-row__song"]/text()')
artists = tree.xpath('//a[@class="chart-row__artist"]/text()')
pairedlist = [list(pair) for pair in zip(artists, songs)]   
for item in pairedlist:
    print (item)
```

What I get (sample):

```
['\nDrake\n', 'Nice For What']
['\nChildish Gambino\n', 'This Is America']
['\nDrake\n', "God's Plan"]
['\nElla Mai\n', 'Psycho']
['\nAriana Grande\n', 'The Middle']
['\nBTS\n', 'Yes Indeed']
['\nCamila Cabello\n', 'Meant To Be']
['\nEd Sheeran\n', "Boo'd Up"]
['\nCardi B\n', 'No Tears Left To Cry']
['\nImagine Dragons\n', 'Fake Love']
['\nShawn Mendes\n', 'Friends']
['\nKane Brown\n', 'Look Alive']
['\nRich The Kid\n', 'Never Be The Same']
['\nMaroon 5\n', 'Walk It Talk It']
['\nNicki Minaj\n', 'Perfect']
['\nPost Malone\n', 'Be Careful']
['\nThe Weeknd\n', 'Whatever It Takes']
```

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/guoguo12/billboard-charts

Comment: `artists = [x.strip() for x in tree.xpath('//a[@class="chart-row__artist"]/text()')]
`

Comment: that worked like a charm.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The python function strip will solve this for you.
See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm).

Comment: I keep getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Comment: That's because you need to apply the function to each of the elements of the list, not the list itself.